# every time i removed my connection DB , my css start to having trouble

Tags: php, html, css, pdo

this is the login php/html file

```
<?php
require'User.php';
// $user = new User();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/login.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="flex-row">
            <div class="half-size meet-side">
            </div>
            <div class="half-size form-side">
                <div class="bgc"></div>
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="form-wrapper">

                        <h1>Please Log in your Account</h1>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <div class="input">
                                <input type="email" class="field" placeholder="Please enter your E-Mail"
                                    name="email"><br>
                                <input type="password" class="field" placeholder="Please enter your Password"
                                    name="password"><br>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="send" name="submit">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the connection.php

```
class DBConnection{
    static protected $db;
    function __construct(){
        if(self::$db = new PDO(DBCON, USR,PSW)){
            echo 'true';
        }else{
            // echo 'error';
        }
    }
}

$db = new DBConnection();
```

and the css are

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* border: .5px solid ; */
}

.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.half-size{
    width: 50%;
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    height: 100%;
}

.form{
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


form{
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    margin-left: 20%;}

.input{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10%;

}

input{
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
::placeholder{
    color: rgb(255, 238, 238);
}
.field{
    border: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid !important;
}

:focus{
    outline: none !important;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #3ca6d8;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #3ca6d8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 1px #3ca6d8;
}
.form-wrapper{
    /* border: 1px solid; */
    padding: 10%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #ffffff78;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.form-side{
    background:url('../images/login/form-side.jpg');
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 9px 15px 33px 22px #69585873
}

.meet-side{
    background:url('../images/login/meet-side.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.bgc{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0000008f;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

everytime i remove require_once 'Connection.php';
my css start to get crazy .

with Connection : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWW9a.jpg)

without Connection : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCh75.png)

[developer tool with connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c09IU.png)
[without connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKkSJ.png)
i tried everything , its just doesnt work for me.
thank you very much about the help!

Comment: my Connection.php is

`
<?php
define('DBCON','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app;charset=utf8');
define('USR','root');
define('PSW','');
class DBConnection{

   static protected $db;
    
    function __construct(){
            

        if(self::$db = new PDO(DBCON, USR,PSW)){
            echo 'true';

        }else{

            // echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
    $db = new DBConnection();
`

Answer (score 0):

do inspect element to find out the issue, on chrome, press Cmd+Shift+C to open the Developer Tools in Inspect Element mode, or toggle Inspect Element mode if the Developer Tools are already open .

you can send screenshot of the page so we can see

Comment: hey, i recently updated my question, the pictures are there